# Why didn't Lord Krishna in His time just tell everyone that He's God so everyone could see God?

Tags: krishna, gods, arjuna

As we know, Lord Krishna had shown his *viswa rupa* (universal form) to Arjuna. So why couldn't Lord Krishna tell everyone that He's God or show his *viswa rupa* (universal form) to everyone so everyone could get to see God and attain His blessings?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably Kriśhna will not show us His Vishwaroopam because we are not as great as Arjuna.

Comment: If he showed his universal form to everyone then all of them would be immersed in Bhakti, who will do work then? Whole economy, reproduction etc.. would be finished in a day. Will need immediate pralaya then.

Comment: The "Apparent" Universe would collapse, if he showed his Universal form to everyone.This is similar to this question [Why doesn't Lord Krishna give Moksha to everyone?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13889/3500)

Comment: @sv. Related question [Why did Lord Krishna tell Bhagwat Gita only to Arjuna and not anyone else?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/5169/3500)

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yeah, he needed it at the time vs. he was great.

Comment: I understand. Not everyone is worthy enough to see Paramatma while living the mortal life. Thank you all for your answers! :)

Answer (score 2):

That would be counterproductive. Not only would that make everyone immersed in worship and the *bhakti*, it would also stop the righteous defeat of the Kauravas, since no one would be unfazed enough to fight.

And additional, why would Krishna do that? Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should do it every time(Examples:Murder).

**I DO NOT WISH TO OFFEND ANYONE**

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! although you have attempted to answer the question , but its always better to back up claims by providing valid  source from authentic Hindu scriptures like Mahabharata or Quotes of Acharyas etc.Pls provide some sources in your answer.

Comment: You should cite authentic sources.

Answer (score 0):

In Udyoga Parva, Krishna went to Duryodhana to avoid war but he did not listen.

> Given away formerly from ignorance or fear, when I was a child and dependent on others, the kingdom, O Janardana, incapable of being given away again, shall not, O delighter of Vrishni's race, be obtainable by the Pandavas.

> **At present, O Kesava of mighty arms, as long as I live, even that much of our land which may be covered by the point of a sharp needle shall not, O Madhava, be given by us unto the Pandavas.'"** [1](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05072.htm)

Krishna later shows his form where Bhishma and Drona could see.

[Krishna unveils his Virat Roop.](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05124.htm)

> Kesava, that slayer of hostile divisions, endued with great energy, addressed Dhritarashtra's son, Duryodhana, and said, '**From delusion, O Suyodhana, thou regardest me to be alone**, and it is for this, O thou of little understanding, that thou seekest to make me a captive after vanquishing me by violence.

> Here, however, are all the Pandavas and all the Vrishnis and Andhakas. Here are all the Adityas, the Rudras, and the Vasus, with all the great Rishis.

> Saying this Kesava, that slayer of hostile heroes burst out into a loud laughter.

> **And as the high-souled Sauri laughed, from his body, that resembled a blazing fire, issued myriads of gods, each of lightning effulgence, and not bigger than the thumb.**

> And **on his forehead appeared Brahman**, and **on his breast Rudra**. And on **his arms appeared the regents of the world**, and from **his mouth issued Agni, the Adityas, the Sadhyas, the Vasus, the Aswins, the Marutas, with Indra, and the Viswedevas.**

> **And myriads of Yakshas, and the Gandharvas, and Rakshasas also, of the same measure and form, issued thence.** And from his **two arms issued Sankarshana and Dhananjaya.** And **Arjuna stood on his right, bow in hand**, and **(Bala)Rama stood on his left, armed with the plough**.

> And behind **him stood Bhima, and Yudhishthira, and the two sons of Madri,** and **before him were all the Andhakas and the Vrishnis with Pradyumna and other chiefs bearing mighty weapons upraised.**

> **And on his diverse arms were seen the conch, the discus, the mace, the bow called Saranga, the plough, the javelin, the Nandaka, and every other weapon, all shining with effulgence, and upraised for striking.**

> And from his eyes and nose and ears and **every part of his body, issued fierce sparks of fire mixed with smoke.** And from the pores of his body **issued sparks of fire like unto the rays of the sun.**

> **And beholding that awful form of the high-souled Kesava, all the kings closed their eyes with affrighted hearts**, except **Drona**, and **Bhishma**, and **Vidura**, endued with great intelligence, greatly blessed **Sanjaya**, and the **Rishis**, possessed of wealth of asceticism, for the divine Janardana gave unto them this divine sight on the occasion.

> **And beholding in the (Kuru) court that highly wonderful sight, celestial drums beat (in the sky) and a floral shower fell (upon him). And the whole Earth trembled (at the time) and the oceans were agitated.** And, O bull of the Bharata's race, all the denizens of the earth were filled with great wonder.

After it, Krishna leaves the assembly with Satyaki and others.

People did see that he is the god.